# PHP check variable against an array of values with or operator

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, operators

So i have this array of values

```
$veg = array('tomatoes', 'potatoes');
```

How do i check this array against my variable but with "or" operator

Something like

```
if if ($veggies == ('tomatoes' || 'potatoes'))  {
 ...
}
```

but i have no idea how to use my array there

Comment: `if (in_array("tomatoes", $veg))...`

Comment: Check out [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
if (in_array($veggies, $veg)) {
    // do something
}
```